# Is it possible to launch YouTube app on Android with search parameter?

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I know that it is possible to launch YouTube app (if it's installed) on Android to watch a specific video. Can we do a similar thing for searching?

I mean I can use YouTube api to make a search but I don't want to do it, I just want to give search parameters to youtube app, so it can make the search for me. (So, instead of opening the web browser to show search results, I want to show the results in youtube app)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
 intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
 intent.putExtra("query", "something");
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

The `"query", "something"` is your search query, for example:

```
 intent.putExtra("query", "cats");
```

Comment: For clarification, the second parameter of  `intent.putExtra("query", "something");` is your search query.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a link like this:
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=madonna

Comment: I implemented it this way, it's a good solution.
The full implementation would be:
```Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + yourStringHere));

startActivity(browserIntent);
```
for anybody who's wondering